# Using android phone camera in opencv?

Tags: java, android, opencv, webcam

Is it possible to connect your phone to your computer via USB cable and use it as webcam? I know there are plenty of software that allows it (at least for wireless), but how to use it in opencv (I am using Java)?

Comment: First, I don't think it is (currently) possible. Second, I don't think this is on topic. Finally, and as justification for the first and second points, can you use it as a webcam in skype **or** in any other web cam application (over USB)? Why would opencv be a special class of *webcam* interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, however I did not test it. First download such an application that allows to use your phone as a webcam and then connect to it via VideoCapture(0) if it's the only webcam attached to your system. This code should be good for testing, if everything works you should see the video in a JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;        
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;        

public class JPanelOpenCV extends JPanel{

    BufferedImage image;

    public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        JPanelOpenCV t = new JPanelOpenCV();
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);

        Mat frame = new Mat();
        camera.read(frame); 

        if(!camera.isOpened()){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        else {                  
            while(true){        

                if (camera.read(frame)){

                    BufferedImage image = t.MatToBufferedImage(frame);

                    t.window(image, "Original Image", 0, 0);

                    t.window(t.grayscale(image), "Processed Image", 40, 60);

                    //t.window(t.loadImage("ImageName"), "Image loaded", 0, 0);

                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
        camera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public JPanelOpenCV() {
    }

    public JPanelOpenCV(BufferedImage img) {
        image = img;
    }   

    //Show image on window
    public void window(BufferedImage img, String text, int x, int y) {
        JFrame frame0 = new JFrame();
        frame0.getContentPane().add(new JPanelOpenCV(img));
        frame0.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame0.setTitle(text);
        frame0.setSize(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight() + 30);
        frame0.setLocation(x, y);
        frame0.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Load an image
    public BufferedImage loadImage(String file) {
        BufferedImage img;

        try {
            File input = new File(file);
            img = ImageIO.read(input);

            return img;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erro");
        }

        return null;
    }

    //Save an image
    public void saveImage(BufferedImage img) {        
        try {
            File outputfile = new File("Images/new.png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

    //Grayscale filter
    public BufferedImage grayscale(BufferedImage img) {
        for (int i = 0; i < img.getHeight(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.getWidth(); j++) {
                Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(j, i));

                int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.299);
                int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.587);
                int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.114);

                Color newColor =
                        new Color(
                        red + green + blue,
                        red + green + blue,
                        red + green + blue);

                img.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
            }
        }

        return img;
    }

    public BufferedImage MatToBufferedImage(Mat frame) {
        //Mat() to BufferedImage
        int type = 0;
        if (frame.channels() == 1) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        } else if (frame.channels() == 3) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        }
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(frame.width(), frame.height(), type);
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte dataBuffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] data = dataBuffer.getData();
        frame.get(0, 0, data);

        return image;
    }

}
```

P.S. I do think your question is off-topic, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create camera activity  and write code given

```
package com.techamongus.opencvcamera;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    // A tag for log output.
    private static final String TAG =
            CameraActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // A key for storing the index of the active camera.
    private static final String STATE_CAMERA_INDEX = "cameraIndex";
    // A key for storing the index of the active image size.
    private static final String STATE_IMAGE_SIZE_INDEX =
            "imageSizeIndex";
    // An ID for items in the image size submenu.
    private static final int MENU_GROUP_ID_SIZE = 2;
    // The index of the active camera.
    private int mCameraIndex;
    // The index of the active image size.
    private int mImageSizeIndex;
    // Whether the active camera is front-facing.
    // If so, the camera view should be mirrored.
    private boolean mIsCameraFrontFacing;
    // The number of cameras on the device.
    private int mNumCameras;
    // The camera view.
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mCameraView;
    // The image sizes supported by the active camera.
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedImageSizes;
    // Whether the next camera frame should be saved as a photo.
    private boolean mIsPhotoPending;
    // A matrix that is used when saving photos.
    private Mat mBgr;
    // Whether an asynchronous menu action is in progress.
    // If so, menu interaction should be disabled.
    private boolean mIsMenuLocked;
    // The OpenCV loader callback.
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(final int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mCameraView.enableView();
                    mBgr = new Mat();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }
        }

    };
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCameraIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(
                    STATE_CAMERA_INDEX, 0);
            mImageSizeIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(
                    STATE_IMAGE_SIZE_INDEX, 0);
        } else {
            mCameraIndex = 0;
            mImageSizeIndex = 0;
        }
        final Camera camera;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
                Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraIndex, cameraInfo);
            mIsCameraFrontFacing =
                    (cameraInfo.facing ==
                            Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            mNumCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            camera = Camera.open(mCameraIndex);
        } else { // pre-Gingerbread
            // Assume there is only 1 camera and it is rear-facing.
            mIsCameraFrontFacing = false;
            mNumCameras = 1;
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
        final Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        camera.release();
        mSupportedImageSizes =
                parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        final Camera.Size size = mSupportedImageSizes.get(mImageSizeIndex);
        mCameraView = new JavaCameraView(this, mCameraIndex);
        mCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(size.width, size.height);
        mCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        setContentView(mCameraView);
    }
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the current camera index.
        savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_CAMERA_INDEX, mCameraIndex);
        // Save the current image size index.
        savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_IMAGE_SIZE_INDEX,
                mImageSizeIndex);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void recreate() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
                Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            super.recreate();
        } else {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mCameraView != null) {
            mCameraView.disableView();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_2_0,
                this, mLoaderCallback);
        mIsMenuLocked = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mCameraView != null) {
            mCameraView.disableView();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
     public Mat onCameraFrame(final CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        final Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        if (mIsPhotoPending) {
            mIsPhotoPending = false;
            //takePhoto(rgba);
        }
        if (mIsCameraFrontFacing) {
            // Mirror (horizontally flip) the preview.
            Core.flip(rgba, rgba, 1);
        }
        return rgba;
    }
```

Disclaimer:Check my blog link 
http://www.techamongus.com/2017/03/android-camera-in-opencv.html